# Subplot grouped legend for grouped bar charts

Tags: bar-chart, legend, r-plotly

I am trying to add a subplot grouped legend to series of GROUPED bar charts in **plotly**. I've found numerous examples of subplot grouped legends for charts generally (like the last graphical example here: https://plot.ly/r/legend/), but I cannot get the "legendgroup = ~" method to work for GROUPED bar charts.

I have survey data from two different years (2017 and 2019) for a number of operating units at my company. I want to show the 2017 and 2019 survey results side-by-side for each operating unit individually in a grouped bar format with a chart for each operating unit. The only element that is not working is the legend for the survey year (2017 or 2019) which I want to work across all the graphs.

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

# Dummy data 
data <- data.table(Group = rep(c("Business_Unit_1","Business_Unit_2"), each = 4),
                   Question = rep(c("Happy","Ethics","Happy", "Ethics"), each = 2),
                   Year = c("2017", "2019", "2017", "2019", "2017", "2019", "2017", "2019"),
                   Prop = c(.9, .95, .8, .75, .7, .8, .8, .97))

# Grouped bar chart 1                    
plot_1 <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = ~ data[Group == "Business_Unit_1" & Year == "2017", (Question)],
            y = ~ data[Group == "Business_Unit_1" & Year == "2017", (Prop)],
            name = "2017",
            type = 'bar',
            marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                          line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)', width = 1.5))) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~ data[Group == "Business_Unit_1" & Year == "2019", (Question)],
            y = ~ data[Group == "Business_Unit_1" & Year == "2019", (Prop)],
            name = "2019",
            type = 'bar',
            marker = list(color = 'rgb(58,200,225)',
                          line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)', width = 1.5))) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Proportion'),
         annotations = list(x = 0.5 , y = 1.05, text = "Business_Unit_1", showarrow = F, xref = 'paper', yref = 'paper'),
         barmode = 'group')

# Grouped bar chart 2
# Right now I am just hiding the second legend
plot_2 <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = ~ data[Group == "Business_Unit_2" & Year == "2017", (Question)],
            y = ~ data[Group == "Business_Unit_2" & Year == "2017", (Prop)],
            name = "2017",
            type = 'bar',
            showlegend = FALSE,
            marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                          line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)', width = 1.5))) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~ data[Group == "Business_Unit_2" & Year == "2019", (Question)],
            y = ~ data[Group == "Business_Unit_2" & Year == "2019", (Prop)],
            name = "2019",
            type = 'bar',
            showlegend = FALSE,
            marker = list(color = 'rgb(58,200,225)',
                          line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)', width = 1.5))) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Proportion'),
         annotations = list(x = 0.5 , y = 1.05, text = "Business_Unit_2", showarrow = F, xref = 'paper', yref = 'paper'),
         barmode = 'group')

# Create the subplot
plots <- subplot(plot_1, plot_2, shareY = TRUE, nrows = 1)
plots
```

The way this code is written, the legend is linked to the first plot only and the second plot's legend is hidden. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `legendgroup` manually, like the names of traces that you did.
Just put, `legendgroup = "2017"` or `legendgroup = "2019"` in `add_trace` and it will work fine.

Here is yours code with this little alteration:

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)
# Dummy data 
data <- data.table(Group = rep(c("Business_Unit_1","Business_Unit_2"), each = 4),
                   Question = rep(c("Happy","Ethics","Happy", "Ethics"), each = 2),
                   Year = c("2017", "2019", "2017", "2019", "2017", "2019", "2017", "2019"),
                   Prop = c(.9, .95, .8, .75, .7, .8, .8, .97))

# Grouped bar chart 1                    
plot_1 <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = ~ data[Group == "Business_Unit_1" & Year == "2017", (Question)],
            y = ~ data[Group == "Business_Unit_1" & Year == "2017", (Prop)],
            name = "2017",
            type = 'bar',
            legendgroup = "2017", ### Legend 2017
            marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                          line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)', width = 1.5))) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~ data[Group == "Business_Unit_1" & Year == "2019", (Question)],
            y = ~ data[Group == "Business_Unit_1" & Year == "2019", (Prop)],
            name = "2019",
            type = 'bar',
            legendgroup = "2019", ### Legend 2019
            marker = list(color = 'rgb(58,200,225)',
                          line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)', width = 1.5))) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Proportion'),
         annotations = list(x = 0.5 , y = 1.05, text = "Business_Unit_1", showarrow = F, xref = 'paper', yref = 'paper'),
         barmode = 'group')

# Grouped bar chart 2
# Right now I am just hiding the second legend
plot_2 <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = ~ data[Group == "Business_Unit_2" & Year == "2017", (Question)],
            y = ~ data[Group == "Business_Unit_2" & Year == "2017", (Prop)],
            name = "2017",
            type = 'bar',
            legendgroup = "2017", ### Legend 2017
            showlegend = FALSE,
            marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                          line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)', width = 1.5))) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~ data[Group == "Business_Unit_2" & Year == "2019", (Question)],
            y = ~ data[Group == "Business_Unit_2" & Year == "2019", (Prop)],
            name = "2019",
            type = 'bar',
            legendgroup = "2019", ### Legend 2019
            showlegend = FALSE,
            marker = list(color = 'rgb(58,200,225)',
                          line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)', width = 1.5))) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Proportion'),
         annotations = list(x = 0.5 , y = 1.05, text = "Business_Unit_2", showarrow = F, xref = 'paper', yref = 'paper'),
         barmode = 'group')

# Create the subplot
plots <- subplot(plot_1, plot_2, shareY = TRUE, nrows = 1)
plots
```

Here the output:

All

[image: all]

Only 2017:

[image: 2017]

Only 2019:

[image: 2019]

Comment: I think is better to use 2 positions in yours `annotations` to avoid overlapping.

Something like:

`annotations = list(x = c(0.1, 0.7) , y = 1.05)`